# Ссылки на строки в C#

Tags: c#, .net

Ссылка переменной строки совпадает со ссылкой той же переменной, приведенной к `object`. Но две ссылки одинаковых строк, приведенных к `object`, не совпадают. Почему так происходит если строки `immutable`? У констант в том же кейсе ссылки совпадают, но не совпадают с введенными строками.

Код приложения:

```
class Program
{
    const string S1 = "123";

    const string S2 = "123";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s1 = Console.ReadLine(); // 123
        var s2 = Console.ReadLine(); // 123
        Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2); // True
        Console.WriteLine(s1 == (object)s1); // True
        Console.WriteLine(s2 == (object)s2); // True
        Console.WriteLine(s1 == (object)s2); // False
        Console.WriteLine((object)s1 == (object)s2); // False
        Console.WriteLine((object)S1 == (object)S2); // True
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему они должны совпадать?

Comment: @PavelMayorov в моем понимании ссылками. Также как константы

Comment: Я добавил полностью ошибочный ответ. Строки в C# иммутабельны, поэтому позволительна оптимизация со ссылкой на один и тот же объект. Неверный ответ удалил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Но две ссылки одинаковых строк, приведенных к object, не совпадают.

Потому что операторы не виртуальны, а определяются на этапе компиляции на основание типов. Если вы сделали преобразование в `object` то будет вызван оператор `==`, который просто сравнит ссылки, а они не равны вот и `False`.

```
class Program
{
    const string S1 = "123";

    const string S2 = "123";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s1 = Console.ReadLine(); // 123
        var s2 = Console.ReadLine(); // 123

        // вызывается оператор сравнения строк
        Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2); // True

        // вызывается оператор сравнения объекта,
        // т.к. это один и тож же то ссылки равны
        Console.WriteLine(s1 == (object)s1); // True
        Console.WriteLine(s2 == (object)s2); // True

        // вызывается оператор сравнения объекта, 
        // т.к. это разные объекты то false
        Console.WriteLine(s1 == (object)s2); // False
        Console.WriteLine((object)s1 == (object)s2); // False

        // тут тоже сравнение объектов, но оно равно, 
        // т.к. это оптимизация компилятора и рантайма, 
        // происходит интернирование строк и создается только 
        // один объект в памяти
        Console.WriteLine((object)S1 == (object)S2); // True
    }
}
```

Также можно посмотреть скомпилированный код: [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoEgBipIAJDSB2Kgbyoe4cgDsAzhiakaDAMqkGAXgYAiUsQDMcgNxUuPfkJFjxxGfMUr1lTd2ZImKBgFkAhtj4AKZjQDaAXQb2oAcwEASnMGTkoeCIYAN18GASlZAGEIQQhcGAA6ACUYewATABknGGdA1QYAegqGYxCImKg4gySUgTTMnPyivhKyyura8MiLUgBOZ3iZWQFiPqqGABUoAFcYOp5mccnpWWcIYAArGDAMQPi56qXV9ZGt5t39o5Oz2fL5q7Wh4c2JhIfD46nGYXBgAMXsuAEn2Gt2cewBz22/yeQNe/TBEKhNxE43hKMCkimDDxgIJaPeK2hPAAvlRqUA===)

Где будет видно какой оператор сравнения вызывается.

Comment: почему ссылки разные, если строки должны быть в одном экземпляре на все приложение? А получается что 3 разных объекта. Или я что-то не так понял в том как хранятся строки в памяти?

Comment: @Kunoichi а компилятор не знает какую строку введет пользователь, поэтому он создает при первом чтении `s1`, а при втором, даже если строки равны, новую переменную `s2`.

Comment: @Kunoichi в случае с константами - компилятор видит что строки одинаковые. В рантайме при каждой модификации строки будет создаваться новая строка (привет та самая иммутабельность), даже если она будет совпадать с уже существующей строкой. Используй метод `Equals` :)

Comment: Но при желании можно сделать, чтобы и строки созданные уже во время работы программы указывали на один объект - с помощью метода `Intern`

Answer (score 1):

В C# существует интернирование строк, это способ хранения только одной копии строк, чтобы под одинаковые строки память не выделялась из раза в раз. Вы можете изменить свой код на следующий

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var first = "1";
    var second = string.Intern(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(first, second));
}
```

и тогда при вводе значения строки уже хранящейся в пуле будет возвращена ссылка на уже имеющуюся строку, если же в пуле нет такой строки, то эта строка будет добавлена и будет возвращена ссылка на неё.

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/224281/) и [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.isinterned?view=netcore-3.1).